# embedd all popular image formats - jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, javascript

In my web page, I can provide a div, in which, if given, is there any plugin or script which will automatically embed the image if the file is a known, (or supporting) image format?? Anybody got a solution??

thanks in advance...`:)`

blasteralfred

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The usual way to show an image in HTML is the <img> tag. You can trust it to support standard JPG, standard and animated GIF, and PNG, as long as they are in RGB mode. Are you asking about image formats beyond that?

Comment: absolutely yes.. is there any way to display some more formats??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no really good way to display image formats beyond GIF, JPG and PNG in browsers. Some support some additional formats (IIRC, IE does BMP, but Firefox does not; Firefox does TIFF) but it's spotty at best.

The best way is usually to convert the image to JPG or PNG using a server side scripting language like PHP. A very fine tool that can convert dozens of formats is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). You need it installed on your server to use it, though.